# Can disable Chatter in org with installed app that uses chatter objects

Tags: apex, chatter, field-dependencies

I work on an app that references chatter objects such as CollaborationGroup, CollaborationGroupFeed and such. 
Previously, I was not able to disable Chatter when this app was installed due to these dependencies.

However, I am now able to disable Chatter in orgs with the app installed. Is this the correct behaviour? Has this changed from a previous release?

I have another app installed on one of my orgs that has an 'Organization-level Feature Dependencies' on Chatter, and there I am not able to disable Chatter because of this.